# Using std::function with union in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to define a class that has functions with different numbers of parameters stored in a union.  The class is initialized with a function object and necessary parameters.  I am getting these compiler errors at the locations marked (1) and (2)

(1) Destructor of '_' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'f_V' has a non-trivial destructor

(2) Destructor of 'MyClass' is implicitly deleted because field 'functions' has a deleted destructor

I simply want to declare a union of different function objects, and depending on the parameters passed-in be able to pick the appropriate function and call it.  Why am I getting these errors and how should I rewrite this code?

```
template<typename VARIABLE> struct MyClass {
    MyClass(VARIABLE *p, const std::function<void (VARIABLE&)>& f) {
        functions.f_V = f;
        ...
    }
protected:
    union _ {
        std::function<void (VARIABLE &)> f_V; // (1)
        std::function<void (const VARIABLE &, VARIABLE &)> f_vV;
        std::function<void (const VARIABLE &, const VARIABLE &, VARIABLE &)> f_vvV;
        std::function<void (const VARIABLE &, const VARIABLE &, const VARIABLE &, VARIABLE &)> f_vvvV;
    } functions; // (2)
    ...
 };
```

EDIT: I am trying to accomplish storage of lambda functions having variable argument lists in a container.  Something like this:

```
std::vector<MyClass<MyVariable>> myContainerOfLambdas;
MyVariable A,B,TO;
auto lambda1 = [this](const MyVariable& a, MyVariable& to) { ... };
myContainerOfLambdas.push_back(MyClass<MyVariable>(A,TO,lambda1));
auto lambda2 = [this](const MyVariable& a, const MyVariable& b, MyVariable& to) { ... };
myContainerOfLambdas.push_back(MyClass<MyVariable>(A,B,TO,lambda2));
...
// iterate over the stored MyClass objects holding the lamda functions and the parameters
// to call them
for(MyClass<MyVariable> & e:myContainerOfLambdas) {
  e(); // here the appropriate lambda function will be invoked with the appropriate values
  // stored in MyClass
}
```

NOTE: For brevity I have omitted the definition of the () operator in MyClass, but it simply calls the right function object with the right parameters.

If you see a better design approach to this, fine, please direct me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Bad idea. Function can hold complex types so how does compiler know which function object, if any, to destroy when the union is destroyed?

Comment: I think when default constructed, function objects are 'empty'.  The compiler will call the destructor of each union member.  Only one of those members is non-empty.

Comment: Don't use `union` in C++.  Use `boost::variant` instead.  `union` should only be used in C code.

Comment: @andrewz: If an object has a destructor, it can't be in a `union`, so the compiler won't ever call the destructor.

Comment: Both GCC and MSVC report this as a compiler error, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I'm trying to store a lambda function.  What do you suggest I do here besides using a union?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I'm using Apple's LLVM 4.2 compiler.

Comment: @andrewz That doesn't make sense as only one union member can be valid.

Comment: Just store all of them and only use the one you want.

Comment: @andrewz: Either store all of them, or use `boost::variant`.

Comment: @Neil: I see what you're saying.  Ya, scratch my answer.

Comment: Whats wrong with a variadic function through variadic templates?

Comment: @Manu343726: Can you provide an example of your proposed solution?

Comment: @andrewz your class is dessigned to hold a function with unspecified number of argumments. The function signature (The number of parameters of the function) is specified when the class (instance) is initialized, right?

Comment: @andrewz and the function holder instance should be mutable at runtime (That is, you can recicle an instance and modify the function signature at runtime)? Or the signature of the function should be the same during the lifetime of the instance?

Comment: @Manu343726: The latter -- the signature of the function will be the same during the lifetime of the instance.

Comment: @andrewz so, why do you need to wrap `std::function`? What you need could be easily done with `std::function`

Comment: @Manu343726: Please show me how.

Comment: @andrewz as far I know you could specify the function signature at the moment  of its instantation (The instantation of the template). With a bit of metaprogramming you could generate a metafunction which gives you the function signature with the specified number of arguments (Your functions are functions with different number of `VARIABLE` parameters).

Comment: @MooingDuck "If an object has a destructor, it can't be in a union" Not in C++11. You can put objects with non-trivial dtor in a union, you'll just have to provide a custom dtor for the union.

Comment: @andrewz: I have one issue with your approach, given an instance of `MyClass` how do you know how many parameters should be passed ? Because if you can never know how to call it, then there is no point in storing it!

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I have a vector<MyVariable> which holds the passed in values (not shown).  Its size tells me which function to call.

Comment: @andrewz I writted an example of the function signature generator using ideone: http://ideone.com/y3RNhp Note that nobody here has clear idea of what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Manu343726: Please see my edit above which I hope explains the purpose of my class.  I am open to better approaches.

Comment: @andrewz: in this case... why not pass the `vector<MyVariable>` as argument ? It would certainly be more adaptable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [unrestricted unions feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Unrestricted_unions) of C++11 to do with you want.  You will need to implement a custom constructor and destructor on the union that constructs/deletes the appropriate active member.

Comment: Although you'd probably need to embed it as an (anonymous) union in a (non-union) class, to store which member is active. The union will probably have an empty dtor, and an explicit dtor call on the active member is done from the surrounding class' dtor.

Comment: @DyP: Correct, because the destructor needs to access the index to the active member, and the index cannot be a member of the union.

Comment: @user1131467: And really, once you've done all that, you will have simply reinvented `boost::variant`, but poorly.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I'll start paying attention to `boost::whatever` if and when it becomes `std::whatever`. :)